# How to query with multiple conditions that won't match on just a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I provided a simplified sample of the table I'm currently working with here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c57e33/1

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders
    (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     customer_id INT, 
     created_at DATE)
;

INSERT INTO orders
    (customer_id, created_at)
VALUES
    (1, '2019-10-09'),
    (1, '2019-10-01'),
    (1, '2019-08-09'),
    (2, '2019-10-09'),
    (2, '2019-10-09'),
    (3, '2019-09-09'),
    (3, '2019-08-09'),
    (4, '2019-08-09'),
    (4, '2019-08-09'),
    (5, '2019-10-09'),
    (5, '2019-10-09'),
    (5, '2019-08-09')
;
```

My problem is that I want to return only the customers with one or more orders on two specific dates and no orders in between. In the fiddle only the customer_id of 5 should match.

After trying many different ways of queries I finally found a way that works using a bunch of EXISTS clauses:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(customer_id) 
FROM orders o1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM orders o2 WHERE o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id AND o2.created_at = '2019-10-09')
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM orders o2 WHERE o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id AND o2.created_at = '2019-08-09')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM orders o2 WHERE o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id AND o2.created_at BETWEEN '2019-08-10' AND '2019-10-08')
```

But I am wondering if there is an easier and more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM orders
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2019-08-09' AND '2019-10-09'
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MIN(created_at) = '2019-08-09'
AND    MAX(created_at) = '2019-10-09'
AND    COUNT(DISTINCT created_at) = 2
```

The `HAVING` clause will filter the groups with matching condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can `GROUP BY customer_id` and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT customer_id 
FROM orders
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING 
    SUM((created_at = '2019-10-09')::int) > 0
  AND 
    SUM((created_at = '2019-08-09')::int) > 0
  AND 
    SUM((created_at BETWEEN '2019-08-10' AND '2019-10-08')::int) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3Y85oKtmcH5SnWkpoWemC8/1).
Results:

```
| customer_id |
| ----------- |
| 5           |
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has nice [boolean aggregate functions:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select customer_id
from orders
where created_at between '2019-08-09' and '2019-10-09'
group by customer_id
having bool_or(created_at = '2019-10-09')
and bool_or(created_at = '2019-08-09')
and not bool_or(created_at between '2019-08-10' and '2019-10-08')
```

The query should be a bit or significantly faster than yours depending on your actual data.